# Kotlin nullable comparison: different expression vs function result

Tags: debugging, kotlin, comparison, nullable, non-nullable

I don't get the following results:
I have a function `alreadyDoneToday():Boolean`. While debugging I noticed an odd behavior. The expression itself returns `true`, but `false` when wrapped inside the function.

[image]

```kotlin
var lastDone: Date? = null
...
fun today(): Date {
    var calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    return toDateWithoutTime(calendar.time)
}
```

My solution was now to add a null-check:

```kotlin
fun alreadyDoneToday():Boolean{
    return lastDone != null && lastDone!! == today()
}
```

I was kinda hoping that I could compare a nullable to a not nullable. Apparently not. However the debugger output is really misleading.

Any clues?

Comment: What type does `lastDone` have and what is that `today()`-function doing? Please share the declaration or the whole code around it. Note also that when you debug the `toString()`-method or lazy evaluations might influence the behaviour or result. You may rather want to setup a unit test instead.

Comment: *My solution was now to add an null-check* where is the null check? *I could compare a nullable to a not nullable* which is the nullable and which the not nullable? Your question is not clear.

Comment: copy & paste error. updated my post

Comment: can't reproduce it... probably there is something else around that influences the result... can you share the whole code? better yet: only those parts that deal with `lastDone`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce it here either. Are you sure you don't have any background threads modifying `lastDone`? What is the implementation of `toDateWithoutTime()`?

Comment: Just as a side note, don't use the old `Date` api anymore, but better use `java.time` (of course only if you happen to compile your kotlin to java code)

Comment: Can't reproduce here, either.  Given the code above, IntelliJ is fine with `fun alreadyDoneToday() = lastDone == today()`.  And yes, in general, you *can* use `==` to compare nullable and non-nullable values.

Comment: You can definitely compare nullables and non nullables:

`val b0: Boolean = true` > `val b1: Boolean? = true` > `b0 == b1` > `true`

tested on the REPL